# To get a link from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi Im currently using codeigniter, Below i have attached the complete code. As i run this Im getting data from database but i want URL field to be link.How to do that. 
 This is my controller:

```
public function ajaxsearch()
{
   if(is_null($this->input->get('id')))
    {
        $this->load->view('input_view');    
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('Infomodel'); 

        $data['Infotable']=$this->Infomodel->Infotable($this->input->get('id')); 

        $this->load->view('output_view',$data);
    }
}
```

Below is the model:

```
class Infomodel extends CI_Model 
{


    function Infotable($search)
    {

        $query = $this
                ->db
                ->select('*')
                ->from('Info_table')
                ->like('NAME',$search)
                ->or_like('URL',$search)
                ->get();

        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return $query->result(); 
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

and two views: one is input_view

And another is output_view:

```
if(!empty($Infotable ))  
{

    $output = '';
    $outputdata = '';  
    $outputtail ='';

    $output .= '<div class="container">
           <div class="table-responsive">
           <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                  <tr>
          <th>No</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Url</th>
                      <th>Tags</th>
          </tr>

           </thead>
           <tbody>
           ';

    foreach ($Infotable as $objects)    
    {   
        $outputdata .= ' 

            <tr> 
            <td >'.$objects->id.'</td>
            <td >'.$objects->name.'</td>
            <td>'.$objects->url.'</td>   
                    <td>'.$objects->tags.'</td>
            </tr> 

    ';
    //  echo $outputdata; 

    }  

    $outputtail .= ' 
                 </tbody>
                 </table>
                 </div>
                 </div> ';

    echo $output; 
    echo $outputdata; 
    echo $outputtail; 
}

else  
{  
    echo 'Data Not Found';  
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  tag inside the table data.

```
<td> <a heref="'.$objects->url.'">'.$objects->url.'</a></td>
```

Comment: have a look at your quotes. this is invalid

Comment: @LelioFaieta Thanks for mentioning I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you want the url to be clickable by the user you can simply change this line:

```
<td>'.$objects->url.'</td>
```

to something like this:

```
<td><a href="'.$objects->url.'">'.$objects->url.'</a></td>
```

This will create a link in the table cell that will send you to the link